# SharePoint Search Dropdown List Is Missing

Tags: search

In the home page of a SharePoint site, the search box is missing the small arrow that when clicked shows search area options, namely:

```
 1- Everything.  
 2- People.  
 3- Conversations.  
 4- Site.
```

I found options in the site and search setting to edit these items, but have not found anything to show or hide them as I suspected.

Looking in the net did not help.

**Any ideas?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That’s the new Microsoft Search bar.  It’s “universal” throughout Office 365 and is completely separate to the old SharePoint Search Bar.

It’s supposed to be a single place to search for relevant items throughout Office 365 (emails, documents, etc.)

See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/overview-microsoft-search) for an overview